# Reading Excel file w/ADO.net - no data (or tables)

Tags: excel, ado.net

This is my first attempt to read an Excel 2007 file via ADO.net, and I must be missing something b/c when I try to run the query, I get an exception.  When I started looking, it's b/c the table (worksheet) isn't there.  Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
        string cs = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=My File.xlsx;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;""";

        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(cs))
        {

            con.Open();

            string query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con); 

            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            DataTable worksheets = con.GetSchema("Tables");


            adapter.Fill(dt);
            .
            .
            .
         }
```

Comment: You do not have HDR in your connection string extended properties http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel-2007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the accepted answer here

[The First Column of the excel file to put in string variable C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328579/the-first-column-of-the-excel-file-to-put-in-string-variable-c)

It works for Excel 2003 but I think it could easily be adapted to work with 2007.

Comment: There's actually not much of a difference between what I have and that solution.  I changed to see if it worked, and it still doesn't.  The issue is that for some reason the worksheet(s) aren't being found.

Comment: This is a guess, but is the space in the Excel file name in the connection string causing the problem?

Comment: The space in the file name was the issue.  Thanks so much...I should have checked that, but just over looked it.

Comment: I'll just add that I have run into the same issue where the exception was saying something about worksheet object not being found, while the truth was that I misspelled the file name. The error message is not helpfull, well it is even misleading!